# How to install Twig in Magento2 (and make it work)?

Tags: magento2, template

I've followed the steps highlighted in this tutorial:
[Tuto webkul](https://webkul.com/blog/use-twig-template-engine-magento2/)

Basically, install twig package v2.2.0 (easy), set template engine in my di.xml file (easy) then use webkul's Twig php class (easy but.).

Problem: as of version 2, Twig no longer uses the Twig_Autoloader class, and now relies on composer for that. But I have no idea how to make it work correctly so far...how to implement a correct setup.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have installed twig with command `composer require twig/twig` which has installed latest twig version.

`Twig_Autoloader` class is present in twig version `~1.28.2` but not in 2.2.0 so if you want a workaround you can install twig version `~1.28.2` by adding `"twig/twig": "~1.28.2"` in `require` section of your project's `composer.json` file. Run command `composer update` once you have updated `composer.json` file. Afterwards given tutorial will work fine for you.

If you are downloading and using Twig 2.x versions through composer, you do not have to mention Twig_Autoloader, because composer already provides an autoloader. So all you have to do it remove the code  `\Twig_Autoloader::register();` and everything should work fine.